# Unity Отключить ходьбу персонажа при обнаружении стены

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Есть персонаж, есть земля, на обоих висят коллайдеры. 
Перемещение через transform.position

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Когда персонаж подходит к стене с зажатой клавишей, то он пытается передвинуться в сторону стены, но его выталкивает и получается дергание персонажа.

Я попытался решить проблему так, проверяю через OverlapCircleAll есть ли рядом стена, если есть, то идти нельзя. Однако все-ровно одно-два дрожания в самом начале осталось. Как это исправить и как альтернативно можно решить данный вопрос?

```
Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll (transform.position + transform.up * 0.5f + transform.right * direction.x * 0.5f, 0.1f);
    for (int i=0; i<colliders.Length; i++) {
        Debug.Log (colliders[i].tag);
        if(colliders[i].tag == "ground"){
            go = false;
            Debug.Log ("1");
        }else{
            go = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Причина в том, что у вас вместе с коллайдером идет rigidbody(ну скорей всего). Когда в Update или LateUpdate вы перемещаете объект через transform, на 1 кадр объект попадет внутрь другого коллайдера, а в начале след кадра, физика вытолкнет обратно его, отсюда и дергание)
Есть 3 способа решения:
 1. Двигать в FixedUpdate

2. Двигать в Update/LateUpdate используя velocity или AddForce на rigidbody
3. Вектор смещения(**dir**)

Длина вектора смещения(**lendir**)

Половина размера коллайдера(**ext**)(использовать радиус у "сфероподобных"(capsule всякие), ну или большую сторону для "угловатых"(box...))

Кидать райкаст вдоль dir.normalize*(**lendir+ext**)

Если райкаст попадет во что-нибудь, вычислить расстояние до точки попадания(**distToPoint**), и если (**distToPoint-ext*С***)<0f, то не двигать, иначе  двигать объект на dir.normalize(**distToPoint-ext*С**). Если не попал, то двигать просто на **dir**.

(я б взял **С=1.01f** - абсолютная погрешность в 1% для небольших величин, можно конечно и относительную взять, но там нужно доп проверки на ноль при делении, можно вообще забить и убрать **C**, но могут быть очень маленькие дергания).

Comment: Исправил проблему используя velocity

Comment: @ВадимМороз замечательно, ну пометь вопрос как отвеченный значит

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй двигать персонажа так:

`transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;`

Comment: а направление в этой строке куда нужно добавить?

Comment: в общем без изменений